# Can't Clone GitHub Repo using SSH

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, ssh

I'm trying to clone a private github repo through ssh.

I've generate pair keys with keygen that are stored in .ssh, inside a non-root user home directory.

```
/home/nonroot/.ssh
```

However, when I try:

```
git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

I get:

```
Cloning into 'discord-bot'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Following [this](https://mhagemann.medium.com/how-to-fix-ssh-permission-denied-with-git-clone-f669b65f90ac#:%7E:text=All%20you%20do%20is%20move,ll%20likely%20encounter%20this%20error%3A&text=Set%20the%20file%20permissions%20to,and%20retry%20sudo%20git%20clone%20.), I've tried:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

And got:

```
bash: /usr/bin/ssh: Permission denied
```

What should I do?

Running Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `bash: /usr/bin/ssh: Permission denied`

means that you try to execute `/usr/bin/ssh` but you don't have the execute permission on the ssh program.

In order to fix this, run the following command:

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/ssh
```

That adds the execute permission to the ssh executable.

Also make sure that you have uploaded your public key to GitHub.

---

The second error is also a permission problem:

> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @ WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE! @ Permissions 0644 for '/home/nonroot/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' are too open. It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others. This private key will be ignored.

This means that other people on your machine have the permission to view your private key.

This issue can be fixed using `chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh`.

This command changes the permissions of the `.ssh` directory do that nobody else can access it.

Comment: This fixed the ssh permission denied problem. However, now when I try to clone something on my github I get `@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @

Permissions 0644 for '/home/nonroot/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.`

Comment: After `chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh` I get the following error: `Load key "/home/nonroot/.ssh/id_rsa.pub": invalid format
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
`

Comment: Yes. I have no idea why cloning doesn't work. I've already added id_rsa.pub to GitHub SSH keys

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot. The final issue was: keys were not known by ssh-agent. Running `ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa` fixed it.